# How to create a Many2Many field of invoice in Odoo 14 CE?

Tags: many-to-many, task, project, invoice, odoo-14

I'm using Odoo 14,
I added in my project.task:

```
 facture = fields.Many2many('account.move', string='Situation', domain = [('move_type', 'in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund'))])
```

So, that every task could have one or multiple invoice (the invoice could be already created, or the user could create one from the form view of `project.task`).

I don't want it to be a timesheet invoice, I want the user could create the invoice as from invoice menu.

I added on my form view of tasks this:

```
   <page name="situation" string="Situation">
      <field name="facture">
          <tree editable="top" create="true">
              <field name="name" />
              <field name="campaign_id" string="Source"/>
              <field name="invoice_partner_display_name" string="Client"/>
              <field name="invoice_date" string="Date"/>
              <field name="amount_total_signed" string="Total"/>
              <field name="amount_residual_signed" string="Reste" />
              <field name="payment_state" string="Statut"/>
          </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
```

**Everything works fine until now.**

and I got this:

[image: screenshot, everything's OK]

when I click on add a line I got

[image: it's also OK,]

But when I select, an invoice I got:

[image: Here appears a problem]

and if I click on create instead of select I got:

[image: i don't want this]

Instead I want a normal form view of an invoice.

I tried to do

```
facture = fields.Many2many('account.invoice', string='Situation')
```

instead of

```
 facture = fields.Many2many('account.move', string='Situation', domain = [('move_type', 'in', ('out_invoice', 'out_refund'))])
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo will hide the invoice lines tab when the move type is set to [entry](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/views/account_move_views.xml#L735) which is the [default value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L154-L163)

The following error:

```
Error: While parsing modifiers for field invoice_date: for modifier "readonly": Unknown field state in domain
```

Is shown when Odoo evaluates the field modifiers (`One2many` field, editable set).

The [invoice_date](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L280-L281) uses the `state` field in the `states` attribute. To fix the error, add the `state` field inside the `tree`